# Strange error in function templates

Tags: c++, templates

I'm learning function templates in C++, so I wrote a simple function to remove duplicates. But the compiler throws following error.

`removeDup is not a function or static data member`

```
using namespace std;  
template <typename T>  
void removeDup(std::vector<T>& vec)  
{  
        std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());  
        vec.erase(std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()), vec.end());  
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Looks fine to me after the edit.  show us how you are calling it.

Comment: What line generated the error? Was it in the code shown here, or at the place where you tried to call the function?

Comment: you don't give sufficient information: what line triggered the error, what files did you include, what other code was in the compile unit ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;  
template <typename T>  
void removeDup(std::vector<T>& vec)  
{  
        std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());  
        vec.erase(std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()), vec.end());  
}  

int main()
{

    int values[] = {1,2,3,3,3};
    vector<int> ints(values, values + 5);
    removeDup(ints);

    for (vector<int>::iterator it=ints.begin(); it!=ints.end(); ++it)
        cout << " " << *it;
    return 0;
}

$ g++ c.cpp
$ ./a.out
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Errors from a compiler are often related.  For example, if you mis-match block-braces, a lot of identifiers not in scope may result.  Quite often, the first is the root cause and it is tempting to disregard the rest.  In this case, it was the later errors thay were important and the first was far from obvious.

The failure to include stack made removeDup confusing to the compiler and it complained first about removeDup.

The code compiled fine for me after adding:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
```

before `using namespace std;`

Without these includes, this is the error I get from gcc 4.2 (silly Mac):

```
template.cpp:6: error: variable or field ‘removeDup’ declared void
template.cpp:6: error: ‘vector’ is not a member of ‘std’
template.cpp:6: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
template.cpp:6: error: ‘vec’ was not declared in this scope
```

the first line is a pretty close match to:

```
removeDup is not a function or static data member
```

Comment: Yes, the OP left that out, but it is not likely to be the cause of the error message (you will probably get something along the lines of "`sort` is not a member of `std`", etc.

Comment: Yes, I got that, and I added that missing `#include` directives are not likely to be the cause of the OP's problem.  The OP needs to show us how he is calling the function, but I don't think this is a helpful answer.

Comment: To elaborate... this is what gcc outputs with the missing header files: http://ideone.com/pyYd3 .  VS gives something similar.  Neither give "removeDup is not a function or static data member".  Now, it *could* be caused by the missing headers, in which case, the error message is just bad (or the OP didn't post all of them), but I think it more likely that the error is actually occurring at the call site for an entirely  different reason.

Comment: @EdS. I would have thought that too, but since the first error matched pretty close (and I ran it before posting this, I just didn't initially add the compiler output) to the only one presented, I added it in the message.

Comment: I mean, you could be right, we can't know without more info.  I'm not downvoting your response.